# How to implement concepts of template without actually using them in my program?

Tags: c++, templates, ascii

Templates are used to pass data type as a parameter so that we don’t need to write the same code for different data types. I am required to implement this feature of templates for an array without actually using templates in my program and "display corresponding message".

To elaborate,
If the user wishes to create an array of `char` type, but if an integer value is entered then accordingly message to enter a character(alphabet) is displayed.The character talked about needs to be **alphabets** only.

This is my code for the `char` array (have used ASCII comparison):

```
    char choice;
    cout << "Enter C for character storing array and I for integer storing array" << endl; 
    //asking user of which kind of data type he wishes to create array of
    cin >> choice;
    int n;
    cout << "Enter size of array: ";
    cin >> n;
    switch (choice)
    {
    case 'C':
    {

        char data;
        char arr[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            cout << "Enter a character value: ";
            do
            {

                cin >> data;
                if ((data >= 65 && data <= 90) || (data >= 97 && data <= 122))
                {
                    arr[i] = data;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Please enter a CHARACTER: ";
                    continue;
                }
            } while (1);
        }
      break;
    }
```

[sample output for char array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6Nv3.png)

But am unable to implement the same for `int` or `double` declared array and user enters any character value. The integer should be **single digit, double digit** or so.
How can one implement this by using the similar ASCII comparison technique?

Or can some other concept be used for it since this method lead to a rather long code.
My main aim is to implement and display corresponding messages.

Comment: As a side note: `char arr[n];` is not standard C++ unless `n` is a constant expression.

Comment: You are probably going to frustrate your users with your current approach of emphasizing "character". Digits are characters. Punctuation marks are characters. In fact, it is impossible for a `char` variable to store anything that is not a character (not all characters are printable, though). Yet despite asking for a character, your program appears to accept only characters that are **letters**. There is a similar issue when you write "create an array of char type", as that does not mean "restricted to letters".

Comment: Probably would have specified the word *alphabet or letter*. Edited to make it more clear.